# Include redirection in the Body

Tags: php

I have the problem in the **header()**. I know that it has to be before any html code, but with that to replace it so that it redirects to another url.

this is code (index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>title</head>
<body>
<?php
$count = 1;
if ($count > 0) {
        header("Location:list.php?incluided");
    } else {
       header("Location:list.php?error");
    }
?>
<body>
<html>
```

How can I replace it?. Thanks.

The solution, add javascript and delete header():

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>title</head>
<body>
<?php
$count = 1;
if ($count > 0) {
        print '
        <noscript>
          <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;>
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">var IE_fix=true;</script><![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
          {
            document.write("redirecting...");
            var referLink = document.createElement("a");
            referLink.href = url;
            document.body.appendChild(referLink);
            referLink.click();
          }
          else { window.location.replace("list.php?incluided"); } // All other browsers
        </script>
        ';

    } else {

       print '
       <noscript>
         <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;>
       </noscript>
       <!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">var IE_fix=true;</script><![endif]-->
       <script type="text/javascript">
         if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
         {
           document.write("redirecting...");
           var referLink = document.createElement("a");
           referLink.href = url;
           document.body.appendChild(referLink);
           referLink.click();
         }
         else { window.location.replace("list.php?error"); } // All other browsers
       </script>
       ';
    }
?>
<body>
<html>
```

Comment: Absolutely unclear what you are trying to ask. What do you want to “replace” here? And with what? And if you say you know that there should be no output created before the header call, then why are you showing code that does not follow that principle?

Comment: You can echo JavaScript window.location inside if else

Comment: @DineshBelakare - and I disable JavaScript ;)

Comment: Then you have no choice other than using php redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$count = 1;
if ($count > 0)
    header("Location:list.php?incluided");
else
   header("Location:list.php?error");
die();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>title</head>
<body>
<body>
<html>
```

Just put your redirection code on top.

Comment: I need add in code HTML, already solved. thanks you.

Comment: Using javascript when you would be able to redirect using PHP looks very cumbersome to be honest...